# Avoid duplication in array of custom object in realm database. When Primary key is exist in the relational table only

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

how to avoid duplications in array of custom objects in realm Database, Below is my code and related JSON Please correct me if I do something wrong in the model.

JSON ->

```
{
  "playlists": [
    {
      "id": "1f23bd3e-cc01-11e8-b25e-784f435e4a9a",
      "name": "disney nostalgia",
      "duration": 361,
    },
    {
      "id": "2e1f0e02-cc05-11e8-9efe-784f435e4a9a",
      "name": "songs from aladdin",
      "duration": 331,
    }
  ],
    "tracks": [
        {
          "id": "3e986a2a-cc01-11e8-bb04-784f435e4a9a",
          "name": "I'll Make a Man Out of You",
          "artist": "Donny Osmond & Chorus"
        },
        {
          "id": "aff8bcee-cc04-11e8-8c18-784f435e4a9a",
          "name": "A Whole New World",
          "artist": "Lea Salonga, Brad Kane"
        }
      ]
}
```

and Models are as follow

```
class Songs: Object, Codable {
    let playlists = List<Playlists>()
    let tracks = List<Tracks>()
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case playlists
        case tracks
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let playLists = try container.decodeIfPresent([Playlists].self, forKey: .playlists){
            playLists.forEach({self.playlists.append($0)})
        }
        if let tracksList = try container.decodeIfPresent([Tracks].self, forKey: .tracks){
            tracksList.forEach({self.tracks.append($0)})
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //
    }
}

class Playlists: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var duration: Int = 0


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case duration
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.duration = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .duration)
    }
}

class Tracks: Object, Codable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var artist: Int = 0


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case artist
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.artist = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .artist)
    }
}
```

and this is how I save the data.

```
SongsData = try jsonDecoder.decode(Songs.self, from: data)
   let realm = try! Realm()
   try! realm.write {
          realm.add(SongsData)
    } catch {
          Logger.log.printOnConsole(string: "Unable to convert to data")
    }
```

How to avoid duplications into the data when there is same response from server.

Comment: This will require using `Set` which is still under development. More info here:- https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/759
For now you have manually check before adding new items that your list don't contain the item you are trying to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `Set` to get rid of the duplicates before adding your objects to a `List`. Just make sure you make your types conform to `Hashable` that you want to add to a `Set`.

Some general advice: you don't need to create `CodingKeys` when the property names match the JSON keys unless you create a custom `init(from decoder:)` method and you don't need to create a custom `init(from:)` method unless you do some custom stuff, like use `decodeIfPresent` and filter duplicate objects. For `Playlists` and `Tracks`, you can rely on the synthetised initializer.

You also don't need to add elements from an array to a `List` in a loop, just use `append(objectsIn:)`, which accepts a `Sequence` as its input argument.

```
class Songs: Object, Decodable {
    let playlists = List<Playlists>()
    let tracks = List<Tracks>()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case playlists, tracks
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let playLists = try container.decodeIfPresent([Playlists].self, forKey: .playlists){
            let uniquePlaylists = Set(playLists)
            self.playlists.append(objectsIn: uniquePlaylists)
        }

        if let tracksList = try container.decodeIfPresent([Tracks].self, forKey: .tracks){
            let uniqueTrackList = Set(tracksList)
            self.tracks.append(objectsIn: uniqueTrackList)
        }
    }
}

class Playlists: Object, Codable, Hashable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var duration: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}

class Tracks: Object, Codable, Hashable {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var artist: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure you don't add any objects twice to `Realm`, you need to use `add(_:,update:)` instead of `add` and use the `primaryKey` to avoid adding elements with the same keys.

```
SongsData = try jsonDecoder.decode(Songs.self, from: data)
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
      realm.add(SongsData, update: true)
} catch {
      Logger.log.printOnConsole(string: "Unable to convert to data")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @David                                                                                                           
    It really help me but now I stuck on one point, what if I get same response from server multiple times or I made server call multiple times then the tracks and playlist get duplicated. how I can solve that with primary key into the given relationship. Or I can delete the table with relationship